# Handling blank input to edittext with number input specified

Tags: android, null, android-edittext

I am having some trouble with error handling when an edittext field(number input) is left blank. So what i want is to store the value of an edittext into a string, then if the value is not "", i will convert to integer and perform some operations. However, the app stops  even before getting to convert to integer line. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
        bConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //number input edit field
            etInputValue = etInput.getText().toString();

            if (etInputValue.equals("")){
                AlertDialog.Builder inpte = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManualInputActivity.this);
                inpte.setTitle("Error");
                inpte
                    .setMessage("Please Fill in all Fields")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.cancel();
                            Intent i4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i4);
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog inptDia = inpte.create();
                inptDia.show();
            }
else{//Do some calculations}
```

Logcat:

```
    10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:490)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.diatrack.app.ManualInputActivity$2.onClick(ManualInputActivity.java:97)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-21 21:18:00.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: On what line do you convert your string to an int? Based off of your Logcat output, it looks like you are actually getting to the code that tries to convert it to an integer...

Comment: Particularly, what is line 97 of ManualInputActivity?

Comment: Line 97 is where i convert to integer:

    Integer bglValue = Integer.valueOf(etInputValue);

Comment: You should add your code up to that point. Hard to say what's happening with only what you've given.